# React this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Keep getting this error while trying to write an app working with 3rd party API

> TypeError: this.setState is not a function

when I try to handle the API response. I suspect it's something wrong with this binding but I can't figure out how to fix it. Here's the code of my component:

```
var AppMain = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return{
            FirstName: " "
        };
    },
    componentDidMount:function(){
        VK.init(function(){
            console.info("API initialisation successful");
            VK.api('users.get',{fields: 'photo_50'},function(data){
                if(data.response){
                    this.setState({ //the error happens here
                        FirstName: data.response[0].first_name
                    });
                    console.info(this.state.FirstName);
                }

            });
        }, function(){
        console.info("API initialisation failed");

        }, '5.34');
    },
    render:function(){
        return (
            <div className="appMain">
            <Header  />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 417, accepted):

The callback is made in a different context.  You need to `bind` to `this` in order to have access inside the callback:

```
VK.api('users.get',{fields: 'photo_50'},function(data){
    if(data.response){
        this.setState({ //the error happens here
            FirstName: data.response[0].first_name
        });
        console.info(this.state.FirstName);
    }

}.bind(this));
```

EDIT:
Looks like you have to bind both the `init` and `api` calls:

```
VK.init(function(){
        console.info("API initialisation successful");
        VK.api('users.get',{fields: 'photo_50'},function(data){
            if(data.response){
                this.setState({ //the error happens here
                    FirstName: data.response[0].first_name
                });
                console.info(this.state.FirstName);
            }

        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this), function(){
    console.info("API initialisation failed");

    }, '5.34');
```

Comment: @TravisReeder, no. There's no mention of bind in the tutorial.

Comment: There probably was 2.5 years ago. 

Comment: I used the arrow function to solve the problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can someone elaborate further on what is meant by "callback is made in a different context"?

Comment: Holy. I spent hours and I could've just done a bind?.... At least its working now

Answer (score 157):

You can avoid the need for .bind(this) with an ES6 arrow function.

```
VK.api('users.get',{fields: 'photo_50'},(data) => {
        if(data.response){
            this.setState({ //the error happens here
                FirstName: data.response[0].first_name
            });
            console.info(this.state.FirstName);
        }

    });
```

Comment: This works well. In fact, the keyword of function should not be shown up in a file of es6.

Comment: Your answer helped me:-)  Using an ES6 class and RN 0.34, I found two ways to bind "this" to a callback function.  1)  `onChange={(checked) => this.toggleCheckbox()}`, 2) `onChange={this.toggleCheckbox.bind(this)}`.

Comment: This is good as long as you don't need to support old browsers.

Comment: Perfect solution

Comment: GMsoF, those two solutions work because a) when you do `.bind(this)`, it sets the value of `this` to the parent context where `this.toggleCheckbox()` is called from, otherwise `this` would refer to where it was actually executed. b) The fat arrow solution works because it retains the value of `this`, so it is helping you by not violently changing the value of `this`. In JavaScript, `this` simply refers to the current scope, so if you write a function, `this` is that function. If you put a function inside it, `this` is inside that child function. Fat arrows keep the context of where called from

Comment: It allows you to nest function calls exactly like this and not have to worry about always remembering to attach `.bind(this)` on it. Look at devdanke's comment again and look how the only difference is `this.foo.bind(this)` vs. `() => this.foo()`

Comment: In 2019, this is the best answer now.

Answer (score 62):

React recommends bind this in all methods that needs to use this of `class` instead this of self `function`.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
}

 onClick () {
     this.setState({...})
 }
```

Or you may to use `arrow function` instead.

Comment: Care to share an example, how would one use an arrow function to solve this issue?

Comment: @DJGruby Normal function: `onClick() {}`. Arrow function: `onClick = () =>{}`. If you want to add async. `onClick = async () =>{}`

Answer (score 41):

you could also save a reference to `this` before you invoke the `api` method:

```
componentDidMount:function(){

    var that = this;

    VK.init(function(){
        console.info("API initialisation successful");
        VK.api('users.get',{fields: 'photo_50'},function(data){
            if(data.response){
                that.setState({ //the error happens here
                    FirstName: data.response[0].first_name
                });
                console.info(that.state.FirstName);
            }
        });
    }, function(){
        console.info("API initialisation failed");

    }, '5.34');
},
```

Answer (score 17):

You just need to bind your event

for ex-

```
// place this code to your constructor

this._handleDelete = this._handleDelete.bind(this);

// and your setState function will work perfectly

_handleDelete(id){

    this.state.list.splice(id, 1);

    this.setState({ list: this.state.list });

    // this.setState({list: list});

}
```

Answer (score 16):

use arrow functions, as arrow functions point to parent scope and this will be available. 
(substitute of bind technique)

Comment: A great succinct solution

Comment: having same issue though used to call the method as an arrow function in the call, but I guess I have to implement the state function as such, and exactly what i have done

Answer (score 10):

Now ES6 have arrow function it really helpful if you really confuse with bind(this) expression you can try arrow function

This is how I do.

```
componentWillMount() {
        ListApi.getList()
            .then(JsonList => this.setState({ List: JsonList }));
    }

 //Above method equalent to this...
     componentWillMount() {
         ListApi.getList()
             .then(function (JsonList) {
                 this.setState({ List: JsonList });
             }.bind(this));
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

You no need to assign this to a local variable if you use arrow function. Arrow functions takes binding automatically and you can stay away with scope related issues.

Below code explains how to use arrow function in different scenarios

```
componentDidMount = () => {

    VK.init(() => {
        console.info("API initialisation successful");
        VK.api('users.get',{fields: 'photo_50'},(data) => {
            if(data.response){
                that.setState({ //this available here and you can do setState
                    FirstName: data.response[0].first_name
                });
                console.info(that.state.FirstName);
            }
        });
    }, () => {
        console.info("API initialisation failed");

    }, '5.34');
 },
```

Answer (score 8):

I have the same error of

`TypeError: setState is not a function`

but the cause is silly. Posting it as a response here to hopefully save people who might be making the same mistake.

Instead of

```js
  const { state, setState } = React.useState(false);
```

Use

```js
  const [ state, setState ] = React.useState(false);
```

**Square** brackets and not curly brackets!

Comment: Thank you, made this silly mistake today.

Answer (score 7):

Now in react with es6/7 you can bind function to current context with arrow function like this, make request and resolve promises like this :

```
listMovies = async () => {
 const request = await VK.api('users.get',{fields: 'photo_50'});
 const data = await request.json()
 if (data) {
  this.setState({movies: data})
 }
}
```

With this method you can easily call this function in the componentDidMount and wait the data before render your html in your render function.

I don't know the size of your project but I personally advise against using the current state of the component to manipulate datas.
You should use external state like Redux or Flux or something else for that.

Answer (score 6):

Here THIS context is getting changed. Use arrow function to keep context of React class.

```
        VK.init(() => {
            console.info("API initialisation successful");
            VK.api('users.get',{fields: 'photo_50'},(data) => {
                if(data.response){
                    this.setState({ //the error happens here
                        FirstName: data.response[0].first_name
                    });
                    console.info(this.state.FirstName);
                }

            });
        }, function(){
        console.info("API initialisation failed");

        }, '5.34');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this and still having an issue, my problem is I was calling two variables the same name.

I had `companies` as an object brought in from Firebase, and then was trying to call `this.setState({companies: companies})` - it wasn't working for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was that I was sending the state and setstate as props to a child component but there was a typo in setstate

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly incompatibility problem between react, react-dom, and enzyme.

Try install the following as I did to solve the problem:

```json
[...]
    "react": "^18.0.0-beta-f320ef88f-20211116",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6"
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use from **arrow function** to handle action.

Answer (score -1):

```
I Just Pass Props from child component to the parent component in react native from the child component is pass this.
 const validate = (text) => {
        console.log(text);
        let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w\w+)+$/;
        if (reg.test(text) === false) {
          console.log("Email is Not Correct");
        
          ({ onChangeText: text })
          return false;
        }
        else {
          // console.log("Email Correct");
          
          props.onchangex(text)<<----------------------- here pass the value to the parent component
          console.log(props.onchangex(text));
          ({ onChangeText: text })
       

        }

 and in parent component i set this value to the state like this
   <InpE
      onchangex={this.propx}<---------- pass the parent function to the child component
      placeholder="Please Enter Email"
          />

propx=(a)=> {
 this.setState({email:a}) <-------- this gives me error TypeError: this.setState is not a function


       {this.state.email=a} <---------------- this line is setting up the state email variable
        
    }
```