# that.setState is not a function, inside an independent function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am getting an error

> that.setState is not a function

I saw the questions 
[React this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

Still I cannot get it to work.

But mine is an independent function. Also I store the context and use it like :

```
componentDidMount(){
    that=this;
}
```

and then

```
updateResult(item){
    result.push(item);
    that.setState({result: result});
}
```

I also bind it in the constructor

```
this.updateResult = this.updateResult.bind(this);       
this.resetResult = this.resetResult.bind(this);
```

I also tried doing on one function

```
onUpdate(item, ()=>{
    itemList.push(item);
    that.setState({itemList: itemList});
}.bind(this));
```

but gives an `UnexpectedToken Error!`

I do pass it like this

```
 <Buttons onUpdate={this.onUpdate} />
```

and then call the function from there, but I am using 'that' for setState.

This is my first application, sorry if there are very obvious mistakes!

Comment: Why do you want to store the context? Can't you just use `this` instead of `that`? The use of the `that` pattern is mostly deprecated with es6.

Comment: And you don't need to bind arrow functions like that!
Can you please post the full component for us?

Comment: @Syberic , my first application, was trying different stuff to somehow get it work :p based on the questions in the stackoverflow as I pointed, I know it's wrong, it gives an error as I mentioned. I still have to learn the right way.

Comment: @Roque, I removed it, but doesn't helps unfortunately, still gives the same thing, again, I was just trying different stuff, to get it to work. :(

Comment: @BhavyaArora i double the full component request to say what's wrong.

Comment: @BhavyaArora Before writing any code for the component, declare the variable as `var that = null` (es5 syntax) and it's global.

Comment: Can't help without a complete example. What is the value of `that`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write like this

```
<Buttons onUpdate={this.onUpdate} />
```

the onUpdate function is bound with window, that's why setState is not defined.

You can do like that

```
<Buttons onUpdate={this.onUpdate.bind(this)} />
```

or declare onUpdate like that

```
updateResult = item => {...}
```

This arrow function will be bound with this (your class)