# How to use react setState with chrome API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I want to use react's `setState` with chrome API but I'm running into an issue...

```
componentDidMount() {

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
        if (request.action == "getSource") {
            this.setState({sourceCode: request.source});
        }
    }); 
}
```

I tried the following but chrome API does not recognize `setState` as a function, so then I tried to first save `request.source` as a variable...

```
componentDidMount() {
    var source = "";
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
        if (request.action == "getSource") {
            source = request.source;
        }
    });
    this.setState({sourceCode: source});
}
```

But when I try the following, `source` remains an empty string. I cannot figure out why since `source` is being set to `request.source`. How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

I am calling a script as so...

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'src/js/scripts/getPageSource.js'
     }, function() {
     ...
```

and inside the script I have the following...

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: DOMtoString(document)
});
```

Where `DOMtoString` function simply returns a string. It is the caught by my `componentDidMount` which I have verified by printing to the console inside the if statement.

It has come to my attention that the `addListener` is asynchronous. Is there any way I can save the result in the state?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Are you aware that setState is asunchronous? If you want to see the result you have to ask for them inside a callback function within setState(). ie:  this.setState({sourceCode: source}, function(){ console.log(this.state.sourceCode) })

Comment: @Makyen inside the `if` statement, if I `console.log` the `source` variable, I get the right output. But outside of the `addListener`, `source` remains an empty string. I'm not sure what else you need.

Comment: We need to see how you send that `source` and what's really inside it obviously :-) Also, yeah, you're incorrectly using asynchronous js as Falk noted.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: I think this is completely on topic, not sure why this is flagged. In any case you're hitting two classic javascript issues. 1) setState is not a function because `this` is getting rebound by your callback function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function and 2) `source` is an empty string because your setstate call will be fired before your callback function above

Comment: @wOxxOm ok see my edit

Comment: Alternate duplicate (for first section of code): [React this.setState is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @azium, then you should be voting to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind `this` so it is unchanged in the event listener

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    if (request.action == "getSource") {
        this.setState({sourceCode: request.source});
    }
}.bind(this));
```

Your second attempt doesn't work because the callback is asynchronous. You need to call `setState` when the callback returns. In your second attempt, you register for the listener but then *immediately* call setState.

Edit:
Alternatively, you could switch to using [arrow functions](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html) instead. This would lexically bind `this` so it would be unchanged.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender) => {
    if (request.action == "getSource") {
        this.setState({sourceCode: request.source});
    }
});
```

Comment: You're using react and JSX - easier to use `=>`

Comment: Agreed. I would add `=>` as an option in your answer.

Comment: I was preferring the KISS approach but added it as an option.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, No, react and JSX are not the reason. `=>` is available because this is running as a Chrome extension. Thus, you only have to consider Chrome as the browser, which supports `=>` (from v45). In addition, other browsers in which such an extension might also be compatible (e.g. a Firefox WebExtension) also support `=>`.

Comment: @Makyen I think Benjamin was implying that OP is probably transpiling with babel already, so in fact the arrow function will not exist in the compiled code.

Comment: @Makyen I have a chrome extension that needs to run on older versions of Chrome (that don't get updated, on intranet) so my mileage varies - but your argument is valid too and probably more so for more users.

Comment: @azium, I understood that. I was pointing out that the fact that this is for a Chrome extension supersedes JSX use (for `=>`). On the other hand, Benjamin Gruenbaum makes a good point about compatibility with older versions of Chrome, if a consideration for the OP. The OP has never mentioned using JSX, thus just assuming its use, or any other transpiler, is not a good idea (even if JSX is often used with React). To a large extent, we're arguing semantics for stating assumptions (or realizing we made assumptions). Assumptions we have all made (older Chrome compatibility not needed/JSX use).