# using data from GET request in react and use in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a `GET` request in my react app that returns team data. I am making this in the parent component and then passing it down to the child `Loop` component.  The `GET` request is working but it is undefined when it gets to the `render` function, presumably because my `GET` request hasn't completed. I have tried to use `componentWillMount` but I was experiencing the same issue.

Is there anyone out there who can see something obvious i am doing wrong? i am quite new to React.

Please see my code below.

```
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
       return {
           teams: []
       }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
       $.get(url, function(data) {
           this.state.teams.push(data)
        });
    },

    render: function() {
       console.log(this.state.teams)
          return ( 
             < div >
               < Loop teams={this.state.teams} / >
             < /div>
          )
     }
});

var Loop = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var teamList = this.props.teams.map(function(team, index){
            return(
                <h1 key={index}>
                    {team.name}
                </h1 >
             )
        }) return <ul > {teamList} < /ul>
    }
})
```

Comment: You cannot change the `this.state` object directly as you do, **[see here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)**. In your case I guess it should be `this.setState({ teams: data })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track: the reason why you get `undefined` is because the request hasn't finished yet.

That's because your code uses `this.state` which changes the state directly. But your request is asynchronous so you need to use `setState`, which update state only when the request is done:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
   $.get(url, function(data) {
       this.setState({
         teams: data,
       })
    }.bind(this));
}
```

See [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Comment: Thats because you need to bind `this` to the callback. `}.bind(this)` at the end of the callback you are passing to the get request will work. If you can, use arrow functions `data =>`

Comment: That means the scope of `this` has changed. So you must bind it to the new context. I made an edit. An alternative is using [ES6 arrow functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35020509/2794702).

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `this.state` should be treated as **immutable** so mutating it directly with `this.state.push` should be avoided. _[Referenced from this link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) (scroll to bottom)_