# React TypeError: this.setState is not a function despite having bound handler

Tags: reactjs

Before flagging this as a duplicate of [React this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function), I have seen and read that.

My problem is that I'm getting this error message even though I've bound the handler.

```
class EditAccount extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    state = {
        showForm: false
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState = {
            showForm: false
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>Edit</button>
                {this.state.showForm ? ( <Stuff/> ): null }
            </div>
        )
     }

    //toggle form visibility
    onClick(e) {
        const showing = this.state.showForm;
        if (showing) {
            this.setState({ showForm: false });
        } else {
            this.setState({ showForm: true });
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> componentWillMount() is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering.

The reason to not use `setState` inside `compomentWillMount`,

**React will use the initial state value from constructor or initialized default state  for  the first render instead of re-render. It not wait for componentWillMount to complete setState call asynchronously.**

So,there is no point in making setState call inside `componentWillMount`. It's nothing more than  that state handler processing which do nothing when setState is called.

Comment: As this is true, it does not address what is wrong with the question. The issue was that `setState` is mutated from a function to an object

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your `componentWillMount`. You are changing setState to no longer be a function but rather an object with the value showForm. You shouldn't be setting state in will mount as react advises against it. Drop that whole function and the code will work as you expect.

meaning `this.setState = { showForm: false }` is changing `setState` to be the object `{ showForm: false }` instead of a function. So yes your error message is correct in that `setState` is not a function

Try dropping the whole `componentWillMount` function

```
class EditAccount extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    state = {
        showForm: false
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>Edit</button>
                {this.state.showForm ? ( <Stuff/> ): null }
            </div>
        )
     }

    //toggle form visibility
    onClick(e) {
        const showing = this.state.showForm;
        if (showing) {
            this.setState({ showForm: false });
        } else {
            this.setState({ showForm: true });
        }
    }
}
```

some optimizations.. you should be able to clean up the code a bit

```
class EditAccount extends Component {
    state = {
        showForm: false
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick }>Edit</button>
                {this.state.showForm ? <Stuff/> : null }
            </div>
        )
     }
    handleClick = (e) => {
        this.setState((old) => ({ showForm: !old.showForm }) )
    }
}
```