# React setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    fileChangedHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.persist();
    new ImageCompressor(event.target.files[0], {
    quality: .6,
    success(result) {
      this.setState({selectedFile: result})
    },
    error(e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    },
  });
  }
```

That is the function above and I want to change state after success but I'm getting `setState is not a function`

and this is how I trigger it:

```
<input style={{display: 'none'}} type="file" onChange={this.fileChangedHandler} ref={fileInput => this.fileInput = fileInput}/>
<button type='button' onClick={() => this.fileInput.click()} className='col m3 btn' style={{textTransform: 'none'}}>Choose image</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Maybe a scope issue? Try binding or using fat arrow definition for the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`success` is regular function that has dynamic `this` context that is determined by a caller (`ImageCompressor`).

Since `fileChangedHandler` method is an arrow, `this` refers to component class instance that has `setState` method.

In order to reach lexical `this` inside `success`, it should be an arrow:

```
...
success: (result) => {
  this.setState({selectedFile: result})
},
...
```

Comment: ooh so that's how to convert to arrow functions, thank you so much I was trying to convert it into arrow function but not in this way, anyway thank you so much!!!!