# How to setState in componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, setstate

Working on this project and trying to call firebase real-time database information then setting a state after calling it so I can use it in the render. This is my code currently but its saying setState is unknown, I've tried to read up on other solutions to this problem but don't understand it, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```html
  componentDidMount(){
    this._getLocationAsync();
    firebase.database().ref('pets/').once('value', function (snapshot) {
        this.setState({ testdid: snapshot.val().name })
     });
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is because `this` in your firebase callback refers to that function itself, rather than the component. Using an arrow function should correctly bind `this` to the component should fix your error:

```
firebase.database().ref('pets/').once('value', (snapshot) => {
    this.setState({ testdid: snapshot.val().name })
 });
```

Read up on **scope** in JS, particularly in regards to the `this` keyword. Definitely important to know, cos it has some weird behaviour sometimes.

Comment: @Jayce444 now after you convert it to Arrow function, the keyword "this" in these function what's?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is made in different context, you need to do :

```
 componentDidMount(){
    this._getLocationAsync();
    firebase.database().ref('pets/').once('value', function (snapshot) {
        this.setState({ testdid: snapshot.val().name })
     }.bind(this));  // bind to current context
  }
```

or with ES6, which i prefer

```
componentDidMount(){
    this._getLocationAsync();
    firebase.database().ref('pets/').once('value', snapshot => { // Using Fat Arrow
        this.setState({ testdid: snapshot.val().name })
     }); 
  }
```