# using axios in componentWillMount method got me an weired error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to use axios in my react code for getting data from the server. I put axios code in the componentWillMount of my react component like this.

```py
componentWillMount()
    {   
        axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/Posts")
        .then(function(response) {
            this.setState({Posts : response.data[0].title});
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

but above code thrown me an error like this

```
TypeError: "this is undefined"
    componentWillMount Redux
```

but when I did slightly change in the code like the code below everything were going right.

```py
componentWillMount()
    {   
        axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/Posts")
        .then(response= > {
            this.setState({Posts : response.data[0].title});
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Another thing that I want to say is the "this" object is active in the componentWillMount

is there anyone tell me the difference between two code above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind your function  or use arrow function

```
componentWillMount = () => {

  axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/Posts")
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({ Posts: response.data[0].title });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

**Edit**

please use `componentDidMount` instead of [componentWillMount](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1575)

```
componentDidMount = () => {}
```

or save the value of this in a variable.

```
componentDidMount = () => {

  const that = this;

  axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/Posts")
    .then(function (response) {
      that.setState({ Posts: response.data[0].title });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

**DEMO**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React', 
      Posts: '',
    };
  }

    componentDidMount = () => {
      const that = this;
      axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/Posts")
        .then(function (response) {
          that.setState({ Posts: response.data[0].title });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Post title</p>
        <p>{this.state.Posts}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

**this**

This is determined at runtime and depending on the code, it can be something different.

*this is*

- determined at runtime, when a function is envoked
- determined by how a function is invoked, not where the function is
  defined
- a reference to an  object.
- will always be an object
- global (this) not available in strict mode

Example 1: *this* = `window`

```js
var name = 'Global';

var callName1 = function() {
  var name = 'Peter';
  console.log('--- From callName1 ----');
  console.log(this.name);
  //console.log(this);
  callName2();
}


var callName2 = function() {
  var name = 'Jane';
  console.log('--- From callName2 ----');
  console.log(this.name);
  //console.log(this);
}

callName1();

var execute = function(fn) {
  var name = 'Mary';
  console.log('--- From execute ----');
  console.log(this.name);
  //console.log(this);
}

execute(callName2);
```

Example 2: not available in strict mode

```js
'use strict';

var name = 'Global';

var callName1 = function() {
  var name = 'Peter';
  console.log('--- From callName1 ----');
  console.log(this.name);
  console.log(this);
}

callName1();
```

Example 3: examining *this* with method invocation

```js
var name = 'global';

var obj = {
  name: 'James Obj1',
  func: function() {
    console.log('--- From func ----');
    console.log(this.name);
    console.log(this); // this reference obj1
  }
}

obj.func()

var obj2 = {
  name: 'Jame Obj2',
  func: obj.func // this reference obj2, but the function is defined in obj1
}

obj2.func()

var obj3 = {
  name: 'Kane Obj3',
  obj4: {
    name: 'Mary Obj4',
    func: function () {
      console.log('--- From obj4 ----');
      console.log(this.name);
      console.log(this); // this reference obj4
    }
  }
}
obj3.obj4.func()
```

With `() => {}` function *this* - is lexically bound. It means that it uses `this` from the code that contains the arrow function.

Comment: "this" is alive in componentWillMount i tested it so why do i have to use bind in this situation? code will be broken when it goes to the function where the setState function located how to bind that function?

Comment: please see the link I've posted

Comment: Yes i saw it but my issue is still exist even i use componentDidMount

Comment: thank you. this is good example of binding componentDidMount it worked perfectly

Comment: cool, I'm glad it's working. I've also added some example of how *this* gets determined.

Answer (score 3):

MDN says:

> An arrow function [...] is an alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the ´´this´´.

If you use a regular function, `this` refers to the function itself (which is `undefined`). When using an arrow function, `this` remains untouched.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `function(response) { ... }` syntax, `this` is not inherited and will be `undefined`. You need to explicitly bind `this` to your React component so that it knows how to find `this.setState`:

```
componentWillMount()
{   
    axios
    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/Posts")
    .then(function(response) {
        this.setState({Posts : response.data[0].title});
    }.bind(this))  // <-- notice the .bind(this)
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

With the `response => { ... }` syntax the `this` context *is* inherited so this binding is not necessary.

Comment: This works, but lacks readability. Rather than binding functions, arrow functions should be used to avoid the extra ``bind`` statement.

Comment: @Neskews I agree completely. But the question was "what's the difference between these two", not "what's the best way to do this".

Comment: thank you. your notice was that thing i was struggling to find it

Comment: @Neskews i've put working example in my question at first but i wanted to see how to bind that function location after "then" expresion in axios command

Comment: Then I'm glad you found your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

**You need to use an arrow function to use `this`**

You cannot use setState to access `this` when you use a `function()` declaration. `this` will return undefined, as its scope doesn't point to the object that you created. So, instead, you should use the code below,

**Working code:**

```
componentDidMount()
    {   
        axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/Posts")
        .then(() => {
            this.setState({Posts : response.data[0].title}); // `this` object points to your object here because of the arrow function.
        })
        .catch(() => { // Same case here
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Also, Junius is right about componentDidMount.

> The best place to make calls to fetch data is within
>   componentDidMount(). componentDidMount() is only called once, on the
>   client, compared to componentWillMount() which is called twice, once
>   to the server and once on the client.
>   [More Info](https://dev.to/torianne02/componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount-5f0n)

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor update, From the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html), `componentWillMount()` is considered to be unsafe for async rendering. If you do choose to continue to use it, you should use `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` or you can just use `componentDidMount()` which is only called once. The “UNSAFE”  prefix refers not to security but instead conveys that code using these lifecycles will be more likely to have bugs in future versions of React, especially once async rendering is enabled.

```
     UNSAFE_componentWillMount()
       {   
       axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/Posts")
        .then(() => {
            this.setState({Posts : response.data[0].title});
        })
        .catch(() => { 
            console.log(error);
        });
       }
```