# UI not updated after setting state

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am performing a tasks that takes a few seconds to complete and am trying to show an animated progress indicator. When attempting to set the state to update the indicator, it only updates after the task has been completed.

I have tried using callbacks to accomplish this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Lion as Button } from 'react-button-loaders'

class xx extends Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    buttonState: ''
  }

this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
}

Test(){
  // Do task that takes some time
  this.setState({buttonState: 'finished'} // End animation
}

handleClick() {
  this.setState({buttonState: 'loading'},
  () => {
    this.Test()
  })
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} state={this.state.buttonState}>Test
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default xx;
```

Without setting the state to finished, the activity indicator only appears after the entire task has already completed.

Comment: And probably you're getting an error in the console. See that question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31045716/863110

Comment: Updated the code, copied over the wrong editor @MoshFeu

Comment: You're missing the task code, it's not hard to do - setState after the task is complete. Since that code is missing that's all I can say. You also don't need to wait on the state change before starting the task.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense to me, if your task is so fast that the animation doesn't have time to run then what's the problem? Why would you want to artificially slow down your task to show an animation? Anyway it's your UX!

Comment: I'm not sure again when exactly you want to hide the animation?

Comment: Updated code, right after the task in Test() @MoshFeu

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the `Task` contains a lot of work. So you want to hide the indicator *before* the heavy code is firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way that comes in my mind to make it not-blocking is to take advantage of `setTimeout()`:

```
function Test(param) {
    setTimeout((param) => { /* ...code */ }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: This may work, but it isn't very "react like" way of doing it.

Comment: @alexr89 what would be?

Comment: @alexr89 there are a LOT of way to make non-blocking code. This is perfectly legit also in react.

Comment: setTimeout  is very error prone, what if it takes 1 millisecond to return - having the user sit for 1000 is not good. What if it takes 2000 to return - you will get the wrong result? In my opinion you should have a "loading" state value, which you set to false on mount, and then to true when Test is called.While "loading" is true, have a spinner or some UI indication that its loading, and then set "loading" to false again when you set "buttonState" in Test. Happy to write a code answer if you'd like.

Comment: @alexr89 for non-blocking function also 0ms works, and this is the most common pattern to avoid blocking functions in JS. You do not understand what this code implies. Cheers.