# React TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

currently I'm writing an app in react that works with .NET Core web api and I'm getting:

`TypeError: this.setState is not a function`

I will explain when I get this error exactly in last paragraph

Now the view is intended to work as follows, on a page I have a table with data seeded from an array of JSON data and couple of inputs next to it. When I click on a table row it will put row data into inputs and I can edit the data from here. Two functions are handling this, first: `editData` is sending POST request to api and then it modify edited object in database. After this request is done second function: `getData` shall run and refresh a table with new, edited data. Here is how it looks:

Constructor:

```
class SomeClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props = props;
        this.state = {
            someArray: [],
            tableData1: "",
            tableData2: "",

            validationSummary: [],
            isSubmitting: false
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this); //function to handle change on inputs
        this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
        this.editData= this.editData.bind(this);
    }
```

Function for getting data:

```
    async getData() {
        return fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/somecontroller/getroute")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    someArray: data,
                    tableData1: "",
                    tableData2: "", //clear inputs
                })
            })
    }
```

And finally edit object function:

```
    async editData() {
        var validationSummary = []

        if (this.state.tableData1 !== "" && this.state.tableData2 !== "") {
            this.setState = {
                validationSummary: [], //clear summary
                isSubmitting: true
            }

            let response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/somecontroller/editroute', {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    data1: tableData1,
                    data2: tableData2
                })
            });

            if (response.status !== 200) {
                validationSummary.push("Something went wrong")
                this.setState = {
                    validationSummary: validationSummary,
                    isSubmitting: false
                }
            }

            else {
                await this.getData()
            }
        }

        else {
            validationSummary.push("Inputs cannot be empty")
            this.setState = {
                validationSummary: validationSummary,
                isSubmitting: false
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that whenever I edit some data and submit it to send request to API, website stops and I get the before mentioned error on `this.setState` line in the `getData` function:

```
    async getData() {
        return fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/somecontroller/getroute")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ //getting error here
```

I've read couple other questions similiar to this but everytime the solution was to bind function to `this` in `constructor`. However as you can see in my code I have binded both `getData` and `editData` functions to `this`. I probably have to mention that when I REMOVE all `this.setState` references from `editData` function, page is working properly and I'm no longer getting any error. I'm pretty new to react so I'm curious as to why I'm getting this error as it is and how can I fix this without removing `this.setState` references from `editData` function, because I need them for displaying error messages.

**UPDATE**

amrs-tech's answer fixed my problem, in `editData` changing `this.setState = {...}` to `this.setState({...})` made it work. Hope it will be useful for someone in future!

Comment: I don't know whether you're doing it right. I hope for declaring and defining state variables you'd use `this.state = {}` , `this.state.<varname>`

For setting a state value, you would use the function like : `this.setState({<varname>:<value>})`

Comment: `editData` is treating `setState` as a variable when it is a function.

Comment: You're treating setState as a variable instead of function.. Instead of this  ``this.setState = {
                validationSummary: [], //clear summary
                isSubmitting: true
            }``
Try this way :
``this.setState( {
                validationSummary: [], //clear summary
                isSubmitting: true
            })``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @amrs-tech it's a typing error on my side, I have updated the question it's this.state.variable in original code

Comment: @SumodhNair i'll try that

Comment: @mamproblem69 Try my answer below, I think that would work in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your editData should be like:

```
async editData() {
        var validationSummary = []

        if (this.state.tableData1 !== "" && this.state.tableData2 !== "") {
            this.setState ({
                validationSummary: [], //clear summary
                isSubmitting: true
            })

            let response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/somecontroller/editroute', {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    data1: tableData1,
                    data2: tableData2
                })
            });

            if (response.status !== 200) {
                validationSummary.push("Something went wrong")
                this.setState ({
                    validationSummary: validationSummary,
                    isSubmitting: false
                })
            }

            else {
                await this.getData()
            }
        }

        else {
            validationSummary.push("Inputs cannot be empty")
            this.setState ({
                validationSummary: validationSummary,
                isSubmitting: false
            })
        }
    }
```

Hope it works. You can refer for some details about React **state and lifecycle** - [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Yes! Changing `this.setState = {}` to `this.setState({})` solved it, thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (this.setState.tableData1 !== "" && this.setState.tableData2 !== "")
```

this is incorrect. It should be like:

```
if (this.state.tableData1 !== "" && this.state.tableData2 !== "")
```

Comment: ahh, yes sorry it's just a typing error actually it's this.state.variable in my original code, I'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

[`setState` is a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), also [state and props are immutable](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#instance-properties-1).

```
// this.state.tableData1
this.setState.tableData1

// this.setState({...})
// and either way its should considered immutable
this.setState = {
  validationSummary: [], //clear summary
  isSubmitting: true
};

// also this is redundant because props are immutable.
this.props = props;
```

Answer (score 0):

another quick way to fix this problem is to keep 'this' as variable

```
async getData() {
var scope = this;
        return fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/somecontroller/getroute")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                scope.setState({ // scope replace 'this' here
```