# this.setState() is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[i want to change state when fetching data is success n the setState cannot to use because get error this.setState is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX3hm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzdSy.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function    is the the problem you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Scope problem, replace your function callback by an arrow function like this:

```
apiServer.getBalance(myData.token, myData.id, response => {
  if (response.success) {
    console.log("Balance success");
    balance = response.success.balance;
    this.setState({ balance: response.success.balance });
  } else {
    //login failed
    console.log("failed");
  }
});
```

Happy coding.