# How to setState from function parameter in React

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am passing the name and value to handleChange function from child component.

Now I want to set the state to the value that matches the provided name.
But I do not know how to set it.

I tried this way(but it gives error - 'this.setState is not a function') :

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
        loanAmount: 348600.48,
        numberOfYears: 70,
 }
  handleChange(name, value) {  
    this.setState({ name: value },() => {
      this.financeCalcualte();
    });
  }
```

The code of the child component is:

```
   onChange = (event) => {   
    const {name, rawValue} = event.target;
    this.props.handleChange(name, rawValue)
   }
```

What is the correct syntax to set it?

Comment: Could you show us more code ? I'd like to see your whole file in order to know if you're in a `component` or `functional component`

Comment: you need to bind `this` (the component class instance). Where are you using `handleChange()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @codeblooded  yes, this answers my question, thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

In order to use `this` in a callback function, as told in the comments you have to bind it in the constructor or use an arrow function.

Also, since your `name` is a variable, you can't update your state like:

```
this.setState({ name: value }
```

because this creates a `name` property in your state, does not update the state variable which has the `name` as your incoming variable. So, you should use a computed property.

```
handleChange = (name, value) =>
  this.setState({ [name]: value }, () => this.financeCalcualte());
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Description)

```
handleChange(name, value) {
    this.setState({ [name]: value },() => {
      this.financeCalcualte();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have this function in a Class based component then you can update your current function to an arrow function like below.

```
handleChange = (name, value) => {  
 this.setState({ name: value },() => {
  this.financeCalcualte();
 });
}
```

The thing is you are accessing `this` without a context being given.

Another way can be you bind `this` to the function. Below is the example to do it the other way inside your constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 // Other code ....
}
```

**EDIT**

Also as mentioned in other answer and comments you have to use computed property name, you can not just use a variable name directly and set it to another variable.

`this.setState({[name]:value})`