# React: this.setState is not a function when trying to log in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to have my app redirect to 'home' once a user has logged in. I do have an onSubmitSignin function that evaluates the log in credentials(from a temporary on page database) and then runs onRouteChange function which is then supposed to change the route to 'home' but instead I get the error "this.setState is not a function".

[image]

New to react, there's definitely something I don't get here. Any insight would be really appreciated, thanks!

App.js code:

```
const initialState = {
    route: 'signin',
    isSignedIn: false
}


class App extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;
}

onRouteChange (route) {
    if (route === 'signout') {
        this.setState({initialState});
    } else if (route === 'home') {
        this.setState({isSignedIn: true})
    }
    this.setState({route: route}) 
}


render () {
const { isSignedIn } = this.state;


return ( 
 <div className="App">
<Navigation onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
{isSignedIn ? <Account /> : <Signin onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/> }
</div>
);
}
}
export default App;
```

Signin code:

```
et database = {
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
  password: 'test'
}

class Signin extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        signInEmail: '',
        signInPassword: ''
    }

}


onEmailChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({signInEmail: event.target.value})
}

onPasswordChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({signInPassword: event.target.value})
}

onSubmitSignIn = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.state.signInEmail === database.email && this.state.signInPassword === database.password) {
    this.props.onRouteChange('home');
  } else {
    return (this.props.onRouteChange('signout'));
  }
}

render () {

  return (
    <div className="form">
    <form>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
      <input onChange ={this.onEmailChange} type="email" className="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email"/>
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
      <input onChange ={this.onPasswordChange} type="password" className="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>
    <div className="signInButton">
    <button onClick={this.onSubmitSignIn} type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  )
}

}

export default Signin;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's issue of binding and losing scope :

Due to the below line you are losing scope of the `this`,

```
onRouteChange (route) {
```

**Solution :**

Either you can bind the function in constructor OR Use arrow function

```
// Either you can bind the function in constructor
constructor() {
 this.onRouteChange= this.onRouteChange.bind(this)
}
```

OR

```
// Use arrow function
onRouteChange = (route) => {
```

OR

```
// I am not 100% sure about this, but it will work
<Navigation onRouteChange={() => this.onRouteChange.bind(this)}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind the context of `this` of your `onRouteChange` function in constructor to your component otherwise this will be undefined.

```
constructor() {
 this.onRouteChange= this.onRouteChange.bind(this)
}
```

Or you can convert your function to an arrow function. Arrow function doesn't create it's own instance of this so it's `this` will point to your class.

```
onRouteChange = (route) => {
    if (route === 'signout') {
        this.setState({initialState});
    } else if (route === 'home') {
        this.setState({isSignedIn: true})
    }
    this.setState({route: route}) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a anonymous function `() => {}` to the `Navigation` component method call like:

```
<Navigation onRouteChange={() => this.onRouteChange} />
```

or use:

```
<Navigation onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange.bind(this)} />
```

Now `this` refers to the Component where the function called belongs to.