# Function returning state[i].setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**What I've tried and my issue**
I started with creating an external function and running it through the `onClick`... this works partly as it sends the alerts on click. See the **services page** on [test.ghostrez.net](https://test.ghostrez.net).
Click the small images to trigger the alerts that show *which if statement*, the`state.active:value`, and the `state.id:value`.
So I know the correct statements are being triggered.

My problem is I keep having  **`state[i].setState is not a function`** returned rather than the state being set as intended.

I have placed the function internally and externally to the *`class Player`* and it returned the same issue.

I converted the function to an internal *arrow function* as suggested [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function).

I converted it to a `const changeActiveField = () => {stuff in here}`

I attempted to bind it `const changeActive = changeActiveField.bind(this)` *as suggested [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

Each attempt returning the same Error
[image]

this is what the debug console returns
[image]

**Here is my current function** *its process > 1. if the `active object` in `state` has the same `id` as image clicked - **do nothing**, 2. if the `active object` has a different `id` to the image clicked **setState `active:value` to `false`** then come back and find the object with the `id === id` of the image clicked and `setState active:true` from `false`.*

```
function changeActiveField(im, state) {
  console.log(state);
  for (var i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
    if (state[i].active === true && state[i].id === im) {
      return alert("if " + state[i].active + " " + state[i].id);
    } else if (state[i].active === true && state[i].id !== im) {
      alert(" elseif set false " + state[i].active + " " + state[i].id);
      state[i].setState(false);
    } else if (state[i].id === im) {
      alert("elseif make true " + state[i].active + " " + state[i].id);
      state[i].setState({ active: true });
      return;
    } else {
      return alert("Nope");
    }
  }
}
```

`changeActiveField` is called here

```
 <div className="thumbs">
          {this.state.ids.map((i) => (
            <>
              <Image
                className="carouselitem"
                rounded
                onClick={() => changeActiveField(i.id, this.state.ids)}
                src={"http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + i.id + "/hqdefault.jpg"}
                size="small"
              />

              <h2>
                {i.id} {i.active ? "true" : "false"}
              </h2>
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
```

No joke I've been trying to resolve this for 4 days now. I'm stumped.

Comment: Please post the code that calls `changeActiveField`

Comment: @Drag13 Added code to bottom

Comment: `setState` is a method of a React `Component` class, not any random object. You must call `setState` on an instance of a class. Typically one does this using `this.setState` from a method of the component, ensuring `this` refers to the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to `setState` on an individual `id`, but what you are actually doing is trying to call `id.setState`

From the code you supplied, each `id` looks basically like this:

```
{active: //true/false, id: //some Int}
```

but in reality your code is looking for this...

```
{active: //true/false, id: //some Int, setState: () => //do something here}
```

You'll need to handle how to find your specific `id` object in that array of ids, and then update your full `state` with the current state AND the modification you are making.

***EDIT://my fault, wasn't thinking.***

I would recommend making a copy of your state array in a new variable, then mapping through that new array variable making your mutations. Then set your state based on that new array objects...

```
let newIdArr = this.state.ids

newIdArr.map(id => //do your stuff here...)

this.setState({...this.state, ids: newIdArr})
```

Lastly, when you `setState(false)` you are overwriting ALL your state to where it will be just `false`, losing all your ids along the way.

Comment: `this.setState({...state,  state[i].active = false });` is saying *',' expected* :/

Comment: Edited answer above

Answer (score 0):

This is the end product of too many days pulling my hair out... but it works now and hopefully, it helps someone else.  *(full component code last)*

I used an `anonymous function` in the `Image` that is being rendered. This finds and updates the `object` in the `this.state` array, first, it finds the ids that don't match the value passed in from the *"carouselitem"* and updates their `active` values to `false`, then it finds the `id` that matches the value passed in and updates it to `true`.

The old `function changeActiveField` is now

```
onClick={() => {
                  this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    ids: prevState.ids.map((ob) =>
                      ob.id !== i.id
                        ? { ...ob, active: false }
                        : { ...ob, active: true }
                    ),
                  }));
                }}
```

I have also moved my `firstActiveId` into the class. This finds the `array object` with `active: true` and returns the `id` value which is placed in the `activevid` to display and play the appropriate video.

```
firstActiveId = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.ids.length; i++) {
      if (this.state.ids[i].active) {
        return this.state.ids[i].id;
      }
    }
  };
```

The `firstActiveId` is used like this to provide playback.

```
<div className="activevid">
          <Embed
            active
            autoplay={true}
            color="white"
            hd={false}
            id={this.firstActiveId(this.state.ids)}
            iframe={{
              allowFullScreen: true,
              style: {
                padding: 0,
              },
            }}
            placeholder={
              "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" +
              this.firstActiveId(this.state.ids) +
              "/hqdefault.jpg"
            }
            source="youtube"
          />
        </div>
```

TIP: *don't over-complicate things like I do*

**Full Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Embed, Image } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "./Player.css";

export default class Player extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ids: [
        {
          id: "iCBvfW08jlo",
          active: false,
        },
        {
          id: "qvOcCQXZVg0",
          active: true,
        },
        {
          id: "YXNC3GKmjgk",
          active: false,
        },
      ],
    };
  }
  firstActiveId = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.ids.length; i++) {
      if (this.state.ids[i].active) {
        return this.state.ids[i].id;
      }
    }
  };

 

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="carouselwrap">
        <div className="activevid">
          <Embed
            active
            autoplay={true}
            color="white"
            hd={false}
            id={this.firstActiveId(this.state.ids)}
            iframe={{
              allowFullScreen: true,
              style: {
                padding: 0,
              },
            }}
            placeholder={
              "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" +
              this.firstActiveId(this.state.ids) +
              "/hqdefault.jpg"
            }
            source="youtube"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="thumbs">
          {this.state.ids.map((i) => (
            <>
              <Image
                className="carouselitem"
                rounded
                onClick={() => {
                  this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    ids: prevState.ids.map((ob) =>
                      ob.id !== i.id
                        ? { ...ob, active: false }
                        : { ...ob, active: true }
                    ),
                  }));
                }}
                src={"http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + i.id + "/hqdefault.jpg"}
                size="small"
              />
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Little simple refactor for you...`.find()` returns the first element that satisfies the condition. Be aware that you might be **assuming your array is always sorted** by id.
`firstActiveId = this.state.ids.find(id => id.active)`